# Python 2.7 Syntax to calculate line segment bearings - Not populating field

Tags: python, math, syntax, bearing

I'm trying to calculate the true north bearing of line segments in a feature class using python 2.7. I have found some posts with information but I need to do this in python modules. (Work restrictions) I've imported math and have made several attempts that don't work. These two attempts are the closest & it may just be a syntax error.

Attempt 1 gives me syntax errors
Attempt 2 does not give me errors but does NOT populate the field.

```
    def bearing():
    field = ["BEARING"]
    arcpy.AddField_management(multi_gap, "BEARING", "DOUBLE", "", "", "10","", "NULLABLE")
    print('Field added')

#Attempt 1 - INVALID SYNTAX
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(multi_gap,["SHAPE@"]) as uc:
        for row in uc:
            row = '{}'.format(180 + math.atan(!SHAPE.lastPoint.Y! - !SHAPE.firstPoint.Y!),(!SHAPE.lastPoint.X! - !SHAPE.firstPoint.X!)) * (180 / math.pi))
            uc.updateRow(row)

#Attempt 2 - NO ERRORS BUT DOES NOT POPULATE FIELD
    field = ["BEARING"]
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(multi_gap, field) as uc:
        
        for row in uc:
            if row[0]:
                startptx = vertex[0].firstPoint.X
                startpty = vertex[0].firstPoint.Y

                endptx = vertex[1].firstPoint.X
                endpty = vertex[1].firstPoint.Y

                field[0] = '{}'.format(180 + math.atan((startpty - startptx)/(endpty - endptx))* (180 / math.pi))
                uc.updateRow(row)

            print('done')#prints
```

Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This code looks very confusing. Can you please clean it up and also write the math in your own words that should happen? Even people willing to help you might not want to dig through the math AND the code. For example: What is `field` doing, what is `arcpy`?

Comment: This does not help.

Comment: To clarify - I have a feature class with approx 1 million features & testing on about 3500.  I am 1) Adding a field 'BEARING" that I need calculated with the angle (aka bearing) in decimal degrees for each line. 2)Using an update cursor to scroll through the data. 3) Using a formula that I found on SO which is taking the tangent of the difference between start points & end points for each line then converting into decimal degree output.

Comment: Hit enter by mistake @xtlc...

Comment: I don't understand what the question is about. Are you asking how to compute an angle between a vector pointing north, and a vector defined by two vertices from your data? How is that related to all the other features that you are talking about?

Comment: Also, this might be due to the way you copy-pasted the code, but the indentation of your code is wrong.

Comment: What is the exact error message for the syntax error on your first attempt? Note that we can't run your code, because it's not self-contained (in particular it looks like you are using some imported modules?)

Comment: What are all the exclamation marks in the line `row = '{}'.format(180 + math.atan(!SHAPE.lastPoint.Y! - !SHAPE.firstPoint.Y!),(!SHAPE.lastPoint.X! - !SHAPE.firstPoint.X!)) * (180 / math.pi))`? I've never encountered this syntax before. Your second attempt doesn't have exclamation marks, maybe that's why it doesn't produce a syntax error?

Comment: *"Attempt 2 does not give me errors but does NOT populate the field."* Have you tried debugging by adding `print("WE ARE HERE"); print(row)` just after `if row[0]:` to see if this condition is true? Note that this `if` is not present in the first attempt. Why is it present in the second attempt but not in the first attempt?

Comment: Also, I think your `atan` formula is wrong. I think it should be `math.atan((endpty - startpty)/(endptx - startptx))` instead.

Comment: Or you could use `atan2` instead: `math.atan2(endptx-startptx, endpty-startpty)`. Relevant: [Wikipedia: Atan2 / North-clockwise convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#East-counterclockwise,_north-clockwise_and_south-clockwise_conventions,_etc.)

Comment: `field = ["BEARING"]` will be overwritten with `field[0] = {} ...` in this code. This is probably not what you want to do. Can you post more (runnable) code?

Comment: You are correct that I had a paren error. Fixed but still not working. I will post updated code but I am trying to simply get the start coords and end coords of a given line. Take the difference & calculate the 'direction' or 'bearing' or angle of the line in decimal degrees. I need this to extend the line in the same direction as the line segment that exists in my data. The print statement i put in is prints for attempt 2 but does not populate the field "BEARING".... and yes I want the bearing overwritten (or just written) to the file. I will also try atan2. Thanks.

Comment: BTW.... the ! indicates the field. Where I have !SHAPE is indicating the geometry object to use in the cursor.

Comment: *"ake the difference & calculate the 'direction' or 'bearing' or angle of the line in decimal degrees. I need this to extend the line in the same direction as the line segment that exists in my data."* If what you want is only to extend the line, then you don't need to calculate its angle in degrees. For instance if you have two points A and B, and compute C = A + 37 * (B - A), then C will be on the same line as A and B, and the distance between A and C will be 37 times the distance between A and B.

Comment: @Stef could you explain why you would use 37 * how this would work on close to a mil records? Confused - thanks.

Comment: 37 was an example. You could use any other number. I'm just saying, if all you want is to extend the line, then calculating angles is not the way to go.